# Which kind of active directory

Tags: active-directory

We exist in a big enterprise (with an active directory where we cant get administrator privileges obviously) and would like to setup a local Active Directory for our development department.

This question is part of a case I can present to the enterprise AD people, defining exactly what we need from them. I do not propose to do this task without them doing some action on their part.

We would like to be able to use our enterprise AD users in our local AD.

In this local AD we would like to put our development servers, some of them will be provisioned from golden images and thrown away on hourly basis or faster.

Part of this exercise is that we want to login to servers existing in our local AD with users existing in the enterprise AD. Using enterprise AD as authentication and our local AD as authorization.

Is this a child domain or an external domain with one-way trust?

Can anyone educate me a bit, maybe with some ideas on how to setup a lab in such a way that we can test against the enterprise AD without having admin privileges in it.

Comment: You can neither create a child domain nor create a Domain/Forest trust without having access to the appropriate credentials in the enterprise AD domain.

Comment: extended my question to point out that I intend to get the enterprise AD people involved at some point.

Comment: Yes it's possible with a trust, but can you push it entirely onto them to make a solution, through any appropriate management? Whatever you come up with, there's a chance they'll say "someone who's not familiar with AD has chosen a terrible solution, we're not happy to support it" and drag it out. For example, why can't you put your development servers in the enterprise active directory? Presumably you aren't developing AD related services, based on your question.

Comment: It is possible, you want to create a new domain within the forrest with a one way domain Trust (Your domain trusts the Enterprise but not the other way round). You will need their help as you will not have credentials. Afterwards you want Domain Administrator privileges in your domain. Your enterprise AD team are best placed to fill in the details.

Comment: What is the actual purpose here?

Comment: Thank you Sam, exactly my point.
The "actual purpose" is, as the question states, is to be able to spin up machines fast, without waiting for our IT department to attach them to the AD. We need the AD attached in order to test the services that are connected to the ent AD, as well as use our normal Ent AD identities on these machines.

Comment: @CasperLeonNielsen This sounds like a political and _people_ issue; not a technology problem.

Comment: ewwhite, you are exactly right. All our (and your) problems are people problems in the root. That doesnt mean we shouldnt solve them pragmatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with a one-way forest trust.  You may also be able to use an external trust, but some narrow edge cases just don't work correctly with an external trust but work ok with a forest trust.  Depending on what you are doing, there may  need to be some accommodation in the production forest to get name resolution working (stub zone/dns suffix search order).

A child domain is not a good choice due to test environments are usually a security risk, and a forest is the security boundary. (Child domain trusts are transitive).  A one-way trust ensures no access from the test environment to the production forest.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It asserts my assumptions. Will mark it as answer tomorrow if no more input are coming.